# Google Analytics does not report any keywords with fewer than 5 impressions

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, content, impressions

I am a webmaster for six websites. I have connected all 5 websites with Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools. Having integrated Google Analytics with Webmaster Tools, I am able to see all keywords and impressions on Google Analytics.

If a single impression is made on my website, am I getting the report as 5 impression for my website?  I am not able to see impressions that are less than 5.

[image: GA image]

Comment: Do you have the tracking code loading inside a loop or more than once?

Answer (score 1):

This data comes from Google Webmaster Tools.   I see the same problem when I view the data through Google Analytics: Nothing is reported having fewer than five impressions.

When I look at the data in Google Webmaster Tools directly, I do see items with fewer than five impressions or clicks:

[image: google webmaster tools few impression and clicks]

When I look at the "same" data in Google Analytics, I see that small numbers of clicks and impressions have been changed to "5":

[image: google analytics gwt data changed to 5]

Google Analytics is making your data less accurate in this case.   Use Google Webmaster Tools directly instead.

Answer (score 1):

dont use this information in Google Webmaster Tools. It isn't going to give you accurate numbers. Just use it as an indication of what Google finds you relevant for.

To answer your question, think of this as resource management. They aren't going to report the long tail of keywords that they measure at 1 impression.